# Inserting Data from Dataframe into Ontology using SPARQL and RDFLIB in Python

Tags: python, string, sparql, rdflib, parseexception

I created an ontology using protegee and now want to insert data using RDFLIB in python. Because I have to write the update sparql statements in string and my data comes in various types including, float64, integer, strings, and Datetime, I had to do some parsing and so not all are working. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
df=df.tail(2000)
for ind in df.index:
pData=df['Product'][ind]
lData=df['Lifecycle left in minutes'][ind]
XLPerc=df['Percent of Lifecycle left'][ind]


q = """
INSERT DATA
{ 
myontology:XP myontology:LifecycleData XL.
myontology:XP myontology:UseCycleData XU.
#myontology:XP myontology:LifecyclePer XLPerc.
myontology:XP myontology:Temperature XTemperature.
#myontology:XP myontology:LifecyclePer XLPerc

}

""".replace('XU', str(uData)).replace('XL', str(lData)).replace('XP', str(pData))
g.update(
q, 
initNs={
    "myontology":Namespace("https://js......../myontology.owl#")
  }
)
```

So I am looping over my Dataframe (df) and inserting it into the ontology. Some are working and some are not working despite using the same method. I am getting ParseException error as follows:

`ParseException: Expected end of text, found 'I'  (at char 5), (line:2, col:5)`
There is a long error code but this is the last line. I can provide more information if needed.
I do not know what the issue is, can somebody help me?
Thank you.

Comment: what are the values of the columns? Only numbers? Or also strings? string values for examples have to be quoted in the update statement as all RDF string literals have to be

Comment: @UninformedUser Thank you for your comment. The values from the columns are in different formats and how I access them also affects their type. `SN                                        int64
Day           object
Temperature  float64
Product          object
Start-time  datetime64[ns]
End-time datetime64[ns]
Usecycle left    int64
Manufacturing date   datetime64[ns]
Expiry Date     datetime64[ns]
Lifecycle left  timedelta64[ns]
Lifecycle in minutes   float64
Lifecycle left in minutes   float64  float64
Percent of Usecycle left    float64
dtype: object`

Comment: The previous comment contains the various columns and their data types. if I do `df['Manufacturing date'].values[1]`, the result is `numpy.datetime64('2021-07-12T19:33:28.833921000')`. But if I do `df['Manufacturing date'].values`, I get a list of `datetime64[ns]` as `'2021-06-28T11:22:45.004533000', '2021-05-28T11:22:45.004533000',`

Comment: not sure if I can follow you - are there rows that are now working or are there other columns that aren't working? Note, in SPARQL literals beyond numbers usually have to be "quoted", For example while `myontology:XP myontology:LifecycleData 123 .` works `myontology:XP myontology:LifecycleData ABC .` does not - strings or dates have to be put into quotes, and for dates for example you also have to append a datatype URI to the literal, e.g. `myontology:XP ex:someDateProperty "2021-07-12T19:33:28.833921000"^^xsd:dateTime .`

Comment: @UninformedUser Thank you for the contributions. I took the statements and ontology to GraphDB and ran the SPARQL queries using direct values such as 123, "Product2", etc. I later came back to python and realized that the replace  functions were not evaluating correctly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to rectify the problem myself.
The `replace()` functions were not evaluating correctly due to too similar variables.
For instance, `myontology:XP myontology:LifecyclePer XLPerc` and `myontology:XP myontology:LifecycleData XL.` both had `XL` as in `XLPerc` and `XL` itself.
So, while evaluating, the `XL` in `XLPerc` was replaced with another value such as `68.23433Perc` and not the expected value`68.23433`, and many other similar errors like this.

I solved this by defining my variables as unique as possible and now it is evaluating just fine.
Thank you everyone for your help.